# Xamarin.Android - Google Sign-In crashes

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-signin

I was able to implement Google Sign-In with NuGet package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth (v60.1142.1) in my Xamarin.Forms / Xamarin.Android app. 
The first initial login (see LoginAsync()) with account popup works, and also the following logins on app start in my Xamarin.Forms App.cs with silent login (see SilentLoginAsync()) works. But, after a few minutes when I open the app again, it crashes immedeately. I just see the splash screen for a second and then it crashes. I'm sure it has something to do with silent login.

Any ideas what it could be? I have also the question why GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context) is not possible in Xamarin.Android. It seems like the entire [GoogleSignIn](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn.html#getLastSignedInAccount(android.content.Context)) class is missing.

```
public async Task<bool> SilentLoginAsync()
{
    //TODO: check why GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context) != null; does not work in Xamarin

    // it probably crashes here!
    var result = await Auth.GoogleSignInApi.SilentSignIn(apiClient).AsAsync<GoogleSignInResult>();
    signInAccount = result.SignInAccount;

    return result.IsSuccess && result.SignInAccount != null;
}

public Task<bool> LoginAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    var googleCallback = new GoogleCallback()
    {
        HandleSuccess = (GoogleSignInResult loginResult) =>
        {
            signInAccount = loginResult.SignInAccount;
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        },
        HandleCancel = () => tcs.SetCanceled(),
    };

    MainActivity.CurrentActivity.GoogleCallbackManager.Callback = googleCallback;

    var signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(apiClient);
    MainActivity.CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

EDIT

---

The exception I see in logcat is the following:

```
Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.LayoutRootPage(Page page, int width, int height)<7999cc4bd5664eca8a72469344172ca3>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPlatformLayout.OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)<7999cc4bd5664eca8a72469344172ca3>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)<7999cc4bd5664eca8a72469344172ca3>:0
Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)<ff199c98c3f84852925dd37a0ef6113a>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.9f75f64b-ae6a-4c2f-a4a8-9e33dca4e092(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.n_onLayout(Native Method)
md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.onLayout()PlatformRenderer.java:63
android.view.View.layout()View.java:19659
android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:6075
android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout()RelativeLayout.java:1083
android.view.View.layout()View.java:19659
android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:6075
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren()FrameLayout.java:323
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout()FrameLayout.java:261
android.view.View.layout()View.java:19659
android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:6075
android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame()LinearLayout.java:1791
android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical()LinearLayout.java:1635
android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout()LinearLayout.java:1544
android.view.View.layout()View.java:19659
android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:6075
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren()FrameLayout.java:323
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout()FrameLayout.java:261
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout()DecorView.java:761
android.view.View.layout()View.java:19659
android.view.ViewGroup.layout()ViewGroup.java:6075
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout()ViewRootImpl.java:2496
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()ViewRootImpl.java:2212
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal()ViewRootImpl.java:1392
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run()ViewRootImpl.java:6752
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run()Choreographer.java:911
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks()Choreographer.java:723
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame()Choreographer.java:658
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run()Choreographer.java:897
android.os.Handler.handleCallback()Handler.java:790
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:99
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:164
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:6494
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()RuntimeInit.java:438
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:807
```

EDIT 2:

---

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        if (await GoogleAccount.SilentLoginAsync())
        {
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage { ViewModel = new LoginViewModel() });
        }
    }

    protected async override void OnStart()
    {
        OnResume();

        await StartAsync();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Check the Application Output or Logcat for error messages

Comment: I added the exception stack trace

Comment: Looking at the stack trace and the Xamarin.Forms code, it would appear that `Page` is null: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/f390b64630d4843b7a80a3f76552cd28b5bfc6b8/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/Platform.cs#L313 Why this happens is unclear. However, it may have something to do with you navigating away from your Forms Activity.

Comment: I added my App.xaml.cs file. I do the silent login within my OnStart method of App.xaml.cs. DO you think it has something to do async stuff within that method?